# How to split a form action which is too long

Tags: php, html

I have this form :

```
<form
 action="/schools/{{$school->id}}/classrooms/{{$classroom->id}}/assignments/{{$assignment->id}}"
 method="POST">
```

And I am using sonar cloud to check that my code is clean.
And in this case , sonar warns me :

**Split this 123 characters long line (which is greater than 120 authorized).**

As I use uuid, the action is something like that

```
<form action="/schools/f2efb5b6-081b-427f-aeec-aafe8d4548db/classrooms/43545307-6a6b-402e-8a08-c4d9d1499148/assignments/33bc5872-bbc1-449e-b9ea-da37f57a0d5f" method="POST">
```

It s certainly trivial but how to split this long string ?
I tried :

```
<form
 action="/schools/{{$school->id}}
/classrooms/{{$classroom->id}}
/assignments/{{$assignment->id}}"
 method="POST">
```

which does not work of course (because the CR).
How would you do that ?

Comment: use concatination to combime some lines with strings

Comment: Did you try anything else? Also, is this problem related to the PHP source code, or to the HTML markup? What keeps you from ignoring that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML has no features for splitting long attribute values onto multiple lines without changing their meaning.

You have three choices here:

- Edit the URL itself to make it shorter (e.g. It seems to have variable names in it: use shorter ones)
- Define the whole URL as a variable on a different line and then add that to the attribute
- Remember that guidance for code formatting should be guidance and not rules.